# Find a limit of sequence (calculus 2)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am having trouble proving that exercise: 
Let there be sequence  $a_{n}$ which:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+2} - a_{n} = 0$
prove that:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n}}{n} = 0$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Please add your own effort/thoughts on this problem so we can help accordingly!

Comment: hi, I have tried using cauchy criteria, and playing with the series of a_(n+2) - a_n , all in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is right. We have
$$
a_{2(n+1)}- a_{2n} \to 0
$$
so by Cesàro's lemma (which says that if $w_n \to l \in \Bbb R$, therefore $\sum_{k=0}^n {w_k}/n \to l$)
$$
\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_{2(k+1)}-a_{2k}}{n}=\frac{a_{2(n+1)}-a_{0}}{n}\to 0
$$
then
$$
\frac{a_{2n}}{2n}=\frac{a_{2n}-a_{2(n+1)}+a_{2(n+1)}}{2n} \to 0.
$$
Using the same method, we have
$$
a_{2(n+1)+1}- a_{2n+1} \to 0
$$
so
$$
\frac{a_{2{n+1}}}{n}=\frac{a_{2n+1}-a_{2(n+1)+1}+a_{2(n+1)+1}}{n} \to 0.
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{a_{2{n+1}}}{2n+1}=\frac{a_{2{n+1}}}{n}\frac{n}{2n+1} \to 0.
$$
Let $u_n = \frac {a_n} n$. We showed that
$$
u_{2n} \to 0 \text{ and } u_{2n+1} \to 0.
$$
Therefore
$$
u_n \to 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you think about another way solving this without using cesaro? Never learnt about it.

Comment: @YotamBerlinsky I'm sorry, I don't see a shorter proof :/

Comment: Alright, the edit explained it, I got it, thank you again.

Comment: @YotamBerlinsky You're welcome. Feel free to accept an answer as you see fit.